# Problems plotting a custom function in R

Tags: r

I would like to program and plot this function into `R`:

[image]

The code I have been using is:

```
js <- sapply( seq(1,50, 1), FUN <- function(x) x^{-4})
pim <- sapply(seq(1,50, 1), FUN <- function(x) 2*pi*x)
beta <- function(x) sum(js*sqrt(2)*cos(pim*x))
```

but while this returns the right values for each point, I am running into trouble when I try to plot it using the curve function as what I get is:

```
   Error in curve(beta, 0, 1) : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pim * x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In js * sqrt(2) * cos(pim * x) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Could you please help me fix that problem and get a working plot? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your `beta` function. When you use `sum` like that is takes the sum of the entire vector for *t = 1,...,T*. You do not want to do this. Instead, you want to evaluate that function for each *t*. So, with a small change to `beta` you can then use the `curve` function.

```
js <- sapply( seq(1,50, 1), function(x) x^{-4})
pim <- sapply(seq(1,50, 1), function(x) 2*pi*x)
beta <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(y) sum(js*sqrt(2)*cos(pim*y)))
}
curve(beta, 0 ,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite amazed you both use `sapply` inside these functions. The formula can be almost literally copied into R:

```
beta <- function(x, n=50){
  j <- seq_len(n)
  sum(
    j^(-4)* sqrt(2) * cos(2*j*pi*x)
  )
}
```

You can use any expression containing `x` in the function `curve`:

```
curve(sapply(x,beta),0,1)
```

gives the same plot.

On a sidenote: if you want `beta` to be vectorized, you could indeed add a `sapply` inside, or you could do:

```
beta_vect <- Vectorize(beta)
curve(beta_vect,0,1)
```

works as well.